# Using nested while loop to print pyramid of stars

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, nested-loops, jcreator

I'm trying to print a pyramid of stars using nested while loops. I know I am able to achieve this using for loops but I want to do it with while loop instead. This is my code so far:

```
public class WhileNest
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int rows = 5, i = 1, j = 1;

        while(i <= rows)
        {
            while(j <= i)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
                j++;

            }
            System.out.print("\n");
            i++;

        }
    }
}
```

The output has to be like this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

But my output is this:

```
*
*
*
*
*
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to reset j like this:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 5, i = 1, j = 1;

        while (i <= rows) {
            while (j <= i) {
                System.out.print("*");
                j++;

            }
            System.out.print("\n");
            i++;
            j = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to assign 1 to j at the end of the outer while loop.

```
public class WhileNest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 5, i = 1, j = 1;

        while (i <= rows) {
            while (j <= i) {
                System.out.print("*");
                j++;
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
            i++;
            j = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(int k=0;k<i;k++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pyramid using two for loops:

```
String STAR = "*";
    String SPACE = " ";
    int SIZE = 10;
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++) {
        int start = SIZE-i;
        int end = (SIZE*2) - SIZE + i;
        for(int j = 0; j<SIZE*2; j++) {
            if(j>=start && j<=end && j%2 == i%2) {
                System.out.print(STAR);
            } else {
                System.out.print(SPACE);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

output:

```
          *         
         * *        
        * * *       
       * * * *      
      * * * * *     
     * * * * * *    
    * * * * * * *   
   * * * * * * * *  
  * * * * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

*Instead of initializing "j" at the beginning, include it in the first while loop that'll do the work.( * will be printed at the beginning of each row)

```
public class WhileNest
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int rows = 5, i = 1;

        while(i <= rows)
        {
            int j = 1;
            while(j <= i)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
                j++;
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
            i++;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int rows = 5, i = 1, j = 1;

    while(i <= rows)
    {
        while(j <= i)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            j++;
        }
        j=1;
        System.out.println();
        i++;
    }
```

You are not reassigning `j` to start from beginning. Your `i` and `j` were always staying same. Re-initialize `j` to 1 after the inner while loop as shown. It will work